# How to pass default value in dynamic SQL query if column not exists in a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a dynamic SQL query which selects table name based on user type.
Here both Admin & User tables have similar columns but Admin table have one additional column 'Col4'.

Now I need to pass this additional column value if the selected table is AdminTable else I need to pass default hard-coded value  in below dynamic sql query.

Is there any SQL keyword or any simple way to achieve this functionality?

```
IF @UserType = 'Admin'                                                                                   
 SET @TableName = 'AdminTable'   
ELSE IF @UserType = 'User'                        
 SET @TableName = 'UserTable' 

SET @SqlQuery = 'SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3 FROM '+@TableName+' WITH(NOLOCK)'
EXEC (@SqlQuery)
```

Answer: Below one works for me.

```
SET @SqlQuery = 'SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3,Case When COL_LENGTH(''@TableName'', ''Col4'') IS NOT NULL THEN Col4 Else 0 END as AdminRole FROM '+@TableName+' WITH(NOLOCK)'
EXEC (@SqlQuery)
```

Comment: What do you mean by " pass this additional column value if the selected table is AdminTable". Do you want to have a `where` clause with Col4  or you want to `select` col4 when usertype is 'Admin'?

Comment: @AB_87 I want to select col4 when usertype is Admin otherwise I need to pass some default value in the select list.

Answer (score 2):

```
IF @UserType = 'Admin'                                                                                   
 SET @SqlQuery = 'SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4 FROM '+@UserType+'Table'+' WITH(NOLOCK)'
ELSE IF @UserType = 'User'                        
 SET @SqlQuery = 'SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3 FROM ' +@UserType+'Table'+' WITH(NOLOCK)' 

EXEC (@SqlQuery)
```

Guess you have to do it this way as an additional column is involved.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply change your query text based on condition.

```
DECLARE @DefaultValue INT = 10
IF @UserType = 'Admin'
    SET @SqlQuery = 'SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3, Col4 FROM AdminTable WITH(NOLOCK)' ;    
ELSE IF @UserType = 'User'
    SET @SqlQuery = 'SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3, ' + CAST(@DefaultValue AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' as C4 ' + 'FROM UserTable WITH(NOLOCK)';


EXEC ( @SqlQuery );
```